# Problemas com formato de data

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, culture

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema usando C# MVC e JQuery UI e no momento estou tendo problemas com os formatos das datas, nos inputs está a data no formato correto "dd/mm/yyyy" mas o servidor está recebendo a data no formato "mm/dd/yyyy".

Aparentemente o culture do `web.config` está correto:

```
<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="true"  requestEncoding="utf-8"/>
```

O `Datepicker` também já parece estar no formato correto, pois está mostrando toda a informação dos meses em português e quando eu seleciono uma data vem no formato correto.

Comment: Só lembrando que essa tag aplica a formatação no lado do servidor. Definiu explicitamente em algum lugar que o Datepicker usa o formato dd/mm/yyyy? Testou usando uma data com dia > 12 (30/10/2014)?

Answer (score 2):

Para funcionar, agora instale o seguinte pacote NuGet:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.Validation.Globalize/

Não esqueça de configurar o `BundleConfig.cs` para adicionar os novos scripts às suas Views.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo você pode tanto como converter ela usando javascript, do formato atual para o formado do servidor.

```
  function converterData(dataString){
       split = dataString.split('/');
      return novadata = split[1] + "/" +split[0]+"/"+split[2];

    }
```

ou com C# (do servidor para o jquery)

```
class Program
{
    static String Main(){
       string str = "11/30/2014";
       string[] data = str.Split('/');
       return data[1] + "/" + data[0] + "/" +data[2];  
    }
}
```

Comment: Essas transformações deveriam ser transparentes, e não dependentes de funções manipuladoras de string criadas pelo programador. Por isso que temos bibliotecas de Globalização, tanto nativo do .NET (como a citada pelo Autor da Pergunta), como a citada na resposta dada pelo Cigano.